# How to ensure that a field in a document is unique in ArangoDB?

Tags: database, unique, arangodb, aql

I had created a collection in ArangoDB and need to say that one field is unique. For example I need to say that in 'user_table' 'email' is unique.
How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ensure uniqueness of a certain attribute in a collection, you can use the `ensureUniqueConstraint` function for the collection:

```
db['user_table'].ensureUniqueConstraint("email");
```

This will create a non-sparse unique index on attribute `email`.

If `email` is an optional attribute, you may want to go with:

```
db['user_table'].ensureUniqueConstraint("email", { sparse: true });
```

As @CoDEmanX mentioned, it's also possible to use the more general `ensureIndex` method and specify index type and uniqueness as parameters:

```
db['user_table'].ensureIndex({ fields: ["email"], type: "hash", unique: true, sparse: true });
```

Comment: Alternatively, `db['user_table'].ensureIndex("field", {unique: true});` can be used for the [exact same result](https://docs.arangodb.com/IndexHandling/Hash.html). Sub-attributes are also support, but not array elements in a certain position I suppose (@stj?)

Comment: That is true. At the moment we are looking into if & how this can be extended.